# I need a regexp which matches a space, the star (*), one or more space and then a word in PHP

Tags: php, regex

Basically i'm reading a custom annotation in a docblock

```
/**
 * This exception is thrown when no constant function is found.
 *
 * @author     Time.ly Network Inc.
 * @since      2.0
 *
 * @instantiator Ai1ec_View_Factory Category_Exception
 * @package    AI1EC
 * @subpackage AI1EC.Config
 */
class Ai1ec_Constants_Not_Set_Exception extends Ai1ec_Exception {
}
```

i get the docblock and then try to get the annotation with

```
 $r = new ReflectionClass($tokens[$i][1]);
 $doc = $r->getDocComment();
 preg_match_all('#^.*.@instantiator\s+(.*?)\n#s', $doc, $annotations);
```

This is actually working but it's not optimal. I tried

```
 preg_match_all('#^\s\\*\s?@instantiator\s+(.*?)\n#s', $doc, $annotations);
```

to say match one space, a star, zero or one space @instantiator one or more space and then get anything until the end of the line but it's not working, no matches. 
Also how could i trim any eventual whitespace at the end of the line in the regexp?

Comment: `#^\s\\*` is not matching a space + star. it's matching a space (\s), a literal backslash (\\\), of which there may be 0 or more (*), followed by another space. If you want to match spaceSTARspace, then it should be `\s\*\s`. Note the single backslash on the star.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `s` flag and no double escaping, try this regex:

```
preg_match_all('#^\s*[*]\s*@instantiator\s+(.*)$#im', $doc, $annotations);
```

**Demo:** http://3v4l.org/cCGbg

Comment: You need the `m` flag for `^` and `$` to match newlines in the middle of the string, maybe that's what he was confusing `s` with.

Comment: Sorry the previous link was wrong but this is not working anyway  (even with m flag) http://3v4l.org/sbUca

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: See edited answer and linked demo.

Comment: The demo does not work but i tested locally and it does work, thanks.